# no matching function for call to 'LiquidCrystal::write(String&)'

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

```
void printOnLcd(String s){
  for (int i =0; i<2; i++){ 
    if( i % 2 == 0){ 
         for(int a=0; a<16; a++){ 
             lcd.setCursor(a,i);
             lcd.write(s);
             delay(200); 
             lcd.setCursor(a,i);
             lcd.write(" ");
         }
    } else {
       for(int a = 0; a<16; a++){
           lcd.setCursor(a,i);
           lcd.write(s);
           delay(200);
           lcd.setCursor(a,i);
           lcd.write(" ");
       }
    }
}
```

Arduino gives me the problem: no matching function for call to 'LiquidCrystal::write(String&)'
Can't I put a string on the screen? what's the problem? I encountered this problem a few days ago and now I don't have a chance to look for a possible solution.

Comment: Pretty sure `write` only works with single characters, not whole strings.

Comment: Your compiler is telling you that the function you are trying to execute does not exist at least with the parameter type you are passing.

Comment: are you confusing `write` with `print` ? I think `print` takes strings but `write` not

Comment: Looks like print is the correct function: [https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalPrint](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalPrint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I don't have a chance to look for a possible solution.

Open a webbrowser, enter [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), enter "Arduino LiquidCrystal", click the first hit:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal  < the Arduino manual btw. Read it!

You're trying to use LiquidCrystal.write, so click [write](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalWrite) and read.

> Syntax
>
> lcd.write(data)
>
> data: **the character** to write to the display

So obviously you can only use this function to print a single character.

Now check wether there is another function that allows you to write a string.

The next function in the list is [print](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalPrint)

Sounds good, let's click that and read.

> Syntax
>
> lcd.print(data)
> data: the data to print (char, byte, int, long, or **string**)

Hey this allows us to display a string!

Try it out `lcd.print(s);`

Alternatively click any of the many examples. Most of them use print.

Comment: Nice, but at the end, in the try it out you end up using `write` instead of `print`